# Excel: Trim text between two specified phrases

Tags: excel

I have an excel spreadsheet of clients. One of the cells is a clob pulled from our database and contains hundreds of words.

What I want to do, is remove everything except the text which starts after "phrase1" and ends before "phrase2" - is there any way to do this in Excel?

i.e.

Text is

> a quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog

I want everything between "brown" and "over", output will be "fox jumped"

Many thanks

Edit: the "I want" wasn't supposed to sound rude, it's just how I would write a requirement in the simplest way to understand. I've tried TRIM and custom filtering but no clue where to go from here.

Comment: "I want..." - not really how this place works. You try something yourself and post a specific question when you get stuck. Suggest you read [ask]. If your strings are always words separated by spaces you could use `Split` (in VBA) or various string formulas if you don't want code.

Comment: In fact SEARCH and MID might be enough to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach, although I'm sure there are more compact versions by some formula wizards.

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH(A2,A1)+LEN(A2),SEARCH(A3,A1)-SEARCH(A2,A1)-LEN(A2))
```

This assumes your original string is in A1, first substring in A2, second substring in A3.

To automatically remove leading and trailing spaces, use this adjustement:

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH(A2,A1)+LEN(A2)+1,SEARCH(A3,A1)-SEARCH(A2,A1)-LEN(A2)-2)
```